# "Cannot assign to conditional expression" using "a = x if cond else b = y"

Tags: python, python-3.8

I wrote a game in which the computer has to find the number you are thinking of. A minimal reproducer for the problem I encountered follows:

```
mini = 1
maxi = 99
guess = 5
answer = 'A'
mini = guess + 1 if answer == 'B' else maxi = guess - 1
```

However, the interpreter says this invalid syntax: `Cannot assign to conditional expression (<unknown>, line 5)`

Comment: The conditional expression is use to select between two expressions, not two statements. Use an `if` statement.

Comment: Can you please extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question? Further, search online for the error message and the language to get an insight into similar problems. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A if COND else B` is an *expression*, not a statement, and both A and B need to be expressions as well.

You cannot use it here. Use a regular `if` statement instead:

```
if answer == 'B':
    mini = guess + 1
else:
    maxi = guess - 1
```

...or, if you *really* insist on abusing newly-added features that Python's maintainership refused to incorporate until recently because they were afraid they would be abused to write hard-to-read code, use `:=` to make your assignments be expressions with side effects rather than statements:

```
(mini := guess + 1) if answer == 'B' else (maxi := guess - 1)
```